# Why is Sklansky algorithm convex hull wrong

Tags: convex-hulls

I stumbled across this incorrect `O(n)` algorithm for calculating convex hulls by Sklansky, but it was later proved to be wrong.

My problem is this:  why is it wrong? 
What is an example polygon that could give this error?
Who figured it out to be wrong, and is there a paper showing it is wrong? (or does anyone have the example used to show it's wrong)

Thanks

Comment: A. Bykat, _Convex  hull  of  a  finite  set  of  points  in  two dimensions_, pp. 296-298.

Comment: I can't find a copy of that paper

Comment: There were two algorithms by Slansky, both incorrect. Which one do you mean?

Comment: The first page of  Bykat's paper is freely available at https://doi.org/10.1016/0020-0190(78)90021-2

Answer (score 2):

Sklansky's 1982 algorithm was proven wrong by Touissant and El Gindy. They give counter examples in:

Toussaint, Godfried T., and Hossam El Gindy. "A counterexample to an algorithm for computing monotone hulls of simple polygons." Pattern Recognition Letters 1, no. 4 (1983): 219-222.

[Counter example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5dXX.png)

Much thanks to Greg Aloupis' survey of convex hull algos: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs601/

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think Sklansky's Convex Hull algorithm is wrong? In my personal experience, this algorithm is correct. I have used it in my projects and OpenCV also has an inbuilt function for it:

```
void convexHull(InputArray points, OutputArray hull, bool clockwise=false, bool returnPoints=true )
```

Note also that the complexity of Sklansky's Convex Hull algorithm is $O(N\log N)$.

Refer this paper for more details."Sklansky, J., Finding the Convex Hull of a Simple Polygon. PRL 1 $number, pp 79-83 (1982)"